# How to find a tree leaf from flat data

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree

I have a tree data similar to this:

```
[0] => 
      id = 5,
      name = "TV",
      parent_id = 1,
      children => 
                  [0] => 
                        id = 6,
                        name = "PLASMA",
                        parent_id = 5,
                        children = null
                  [1] =>
                        id = 7,
                        name = "LCD",
                        parent_id = 5,
                        children =>
                                    [0] =>
                                          id = 8,
                                          name = "Gloss",
                                          parent_id = 7,
                                          children = null
                                    [1] =>
                                          id = 9,
                                          name = "Matte",
                                          parent_id = 7,
                                          children = null
[1] =>
      id = 4,
      name = "Printers",
      parent_id = 1,
      children =>
                 ....
```

And I have a flat string data like:

- TV
- TV_PLASMA_Gloss
- TV_LCD

The '_' is a delimiter for a subcategory.

What will be the best algorithm to find an array of category IDs?

Example input:

1. TV
2. TV_PLASMA_Gloss
3. TV_LCD

Example output:

1. array: 5
2. array: 5, 6, 8
3. array: 5, 7

The language does not matter - it is only an algorithm - but in this case I will prefer C#.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `HashMap` (`Dictionary<string, int>` in this case would be fine), iterate through your tree and add (name, id) pairs to the HashMap.

For any input you pass in the input string and the hashmap.

- split the string on the delimiter, in this case '_'  (`input.Split(new char[]{'_'})`)
- for each string part, look up its id in the hashmap, and add it to an output string or array

*

```
public int[] GetIDsFromString(string input, Dictionary<string, int> lookup)
{
  string stringParts = input.Split(new char[]{'_'});
  int[] retval = new int[stringParts.Length];
  int retIndex = 0;
  foreach(var s in stringParts)
    if (lookup.contains(s))
      retval[retIndex++] = lookup[s];
    else
      throw new Exception(string.format("string contained invalid item {0}", s));
  return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary for the (reverse) lookup of IDs related to names

```
Dictionary<string,int> ids = new Dictionary<string,int>();
ids.Add("TV", 5);
ids.Add("PLASMA", 6);
// And so on
```

Now, split the input strings before looking up the ids

```
string input = "TV_PLASMA_Gloss";
string[] categories = input.Split('_');
int[] result = new int[categories.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < categories.Length; i++) {
    int id;
    if (ids.TryGetValue(categories[i], out id)) {
        result[i] = id;
    } else {
        result[i] = -1; // Unknown category
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats the way, I would do it using recursion:

Define a function, which takes a string array and your struct/object-array or whatever.
The string array is parsed before calling the function:

```
string = "TV_PLASMA_Gloss"
array[0] = "TV"
array[1] = "PLASMA"
array[2] = "Gloss"
```

The first string in the array will be tested against all "top level" entries. If there was a matching entry, the function will be called again with the remaining array and the matched entry.

If there is only one string left in the array, we return the id of the found entry. This way we go up our recursive calls and build the integer-id-array we want.

The call hierarchy would look like:

```
-> function({"TV","PLASMA","Gloss"}, entry)
   -> function({"PLASMA","Gloss"}, matched_entry)
       -> function({"Gloss"}, matched_entry)
       <- id = 8
   <- id = 6,8
<- id = 5,6,8
```